# Does `listsinceblock` show coinbase transactions on a watch-only address?

Tags: coinbase-transaction, watch-only

If I have a wallet where I've imported someone's address "A" as a watch-only address, and I run `listsinceblock` (the specific parameters may be irrelevant to this question), would I be able to see the coinbase transactions where the output was "A"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does `listsinceblock` show coinbase transactions on a watch-only address?

Yes. You can use `include_watchonly` argument in [`listsinceblock`](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/wallet/listsinceblock/)

`include_watchonly`: boolean, optional, default=true for watch-only wallets, otherwise false. Includes transactions to watch-only addresses (see `importaddress`)